# Orchard Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory when rewrite URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes, iis-7.5, orchardcms

I follow this article http://english.orchardproject.hu/blog/how-to-create-a-minisite-inside-your-orchard-website, the url rewrite working well, but an error occur whenever I use Url.Action or Url.Content:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Source Error:


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\49abd316\41cc7eb1\App_Web_l2fggwoq.2.cs    Line: 0

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.]
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path) +12805032
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Reduce(String path) +169
   System.Web.VirtualPath.Combine(VirtualPath relativePath) +222
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +313
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +121
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String basePath, String path, Object[] pathParts) +241
   Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage`1.Href(String path, Object[] pathParts) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\Razor\WebViewPage.cs:212
   ASP._Page_Themes_TheThemeMachine_Views_Branding_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\49abd316\41cc7eb1\App_Web_l2fggwoq.2.cs:0
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:151
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.Zone(Object Display, Object Shape, TextWriter Output) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:267

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:65
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   ASP._Page_Themes_TheThemeMachine_Views_Layout_cshtml.<Execute>b__9b(Object x) in d:\projects\test.local\Orchard\Themes\TheThemeMachine\Views\Layout.cshtml:20
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object ) +95
   ASP._Page_Themes_TheThemeMachine_Views_Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\projects\test.local\Orchard\Themes\TheThemeMachine\Views\Layout.cshtml:60
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:151
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:63
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:159
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

When I try to comment the second rule

```
<rule name="Lulz rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(Media|Themes|Modules|Core)" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^lulz.lombiq.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="lulz{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

The site working, but the Layer rule in Widgets not working.

I have try with new installation and the same error occurred.

Even in The Theme Machine without any custom: ASP._Page_Themes_TheThemeMachine_Views_Branding_cshtml

Could you help me to solve this problem?

My scenario is:

- I have a main site running on domain.com
- And many mini-site running on domain1.com, domain2.com...
- All site share the same database, just different by content displayed

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of all that and understanding how the different pieces fit together. First, not being able to escape the site's root has nothing to do with Orchard, it's an ASP.NET security feature. Second, why are you not just using multi-tenancy?

Comment: To answer your questions:  1. I do not try to escape the site's root, I am trying to rewrite the URL.  2. If you read my scenario at the end, you could see that I want mini-site which is use the same database with main site. That why multi-tenancy is not a choice.

Comment: It's not clear why or how you're rewriting the URL.
Multi-tenancy can be configured to use the same database across sites, but different contents. For example, weblogs.asp.net uses one database for hundreds of sites.
You really need to clarify your question, what you are trying to do, what you attempted, what you expected, and how it failed.

Comment: I quote this from the article above: Suppose you'd like to have a minisite for something like a one-page little website or even a simpler single page app. You want to do something simple but you still want your administrators to be able to edit the minisite's content. Let's see how to do this in Orchard, the simple way.

First of all, we won't create a new tenant because that would be a huge overkill. What we'll do is that we'll simply employ a convention of placing every content under a specific URL and map our minisite to that URL pattern.

Comment: To be simple, on domain.com I want to display content [foo] and [bar]. But on domain-1.com, I just want to display [bar] only. And the visitor will have no idea that [bar] is original from domain.com

Comment: Oh, so you actually want to syndicate select contents between sites? It's still extremely unclear how redirects are necessary for that, but it seems like a custom theme selector, together with taxonomies, could provide a much simpler solution.

Comment: Also, I disagree with the authors of that article that it's "the easy way". I see that you commented on the article and got an answer from the authors. Good luck.